# Why is Gendo Ikari called Shinji by Kaworu in "The End of Evangelion"?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, netflix

In the recent Italian re-dub of *The End of Evangelion*, just before Gendo

> is seen eaten by the EVA-01 and dying,

Kaworu called him Shinji.

However, this is missing in the English version.

Why does Kaworu call Gendo as Shinji?

Comment: That's definitely not in the original Japanese script